# How to change a PNG color without CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an `<img>` tag with a `.png` source and I need to apply a color change to it. I tried the `filter` property in CSS but apparently it’s not supported in IE. Any idea if I can do that with JavaScript?

Comment: Paste the code which you have already tried. We will correct you over that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725287/change-color-of-image-in-javascript

Comment: http://camanjs.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve this in two way:

1. by using different png source files, changing them at the occurrence of an event:

   - with pure JavaScript:

     `var image = document.getElementById("my_image");`

     `image.src = "image_1.jpg";`
   - with jQuery:

     `$("#my_image").attr("src","image1.jpg");`
2. by giving a transparency to your png to show a `background-color` applied below it:

   - with pure JavaScript:

     `var image = document.getElementById("my_image");`

     `image.style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff"; // or "blue" or "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)"`
   - with jQuery:

     `$("#my_image").css({ "background-color" : "#0000ff"});`

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the thing is my .png icon has transparent background so changing the background color will change the entire img background. Trying to find a way to manipulate pixels of certain color.

Comment: After the other one option (by using different png source files), another that come in my mind is to use ImageMagick on a web server... take a look on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495371/imagemagick-on-web-server Cheers

Comment: Instead of a transparant background overlay the image with a colored semi transparant element. Even cleaner is to use the :after pseudo element of the image for this purpose